# Generating summary report from jtl

Tags: jmeter

After running a JMeter load test from command line(`nonGUI mode`), I would like to have a summary report with each transaction, Avg response times, #of transactions and so on.  I tried to achieve it by importing `summary_report.jtl` file by following the steps.

1. Open JMeter-UI
2. Add Summary Report Listener
3. Browse the `summary_report.jtl` file that is created during the test.

Now I am seeing all the transactions, `#samples, Error%` and so on.  But average, min, max and std deviation values are `ZERO`.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you see the raw file and check if the latency has been captured properly? If your JTL didn't capture latency you may see all the metrics as 0.

Also check if there is any exception in jmeter.log file when you try to open the jtl. Might help with debugging.
(Also, you mentioned summary_report.jtl, check if your JTL has all the samples or it's a summary report itself.)

Comment: Yes, jtl file has latency values.  

`timeStamp;elapsed;label;responseCode;responseMessage;threadName;dataType;success;bytes;grpThreads;allThreads;Filename;Latency;SampleCount;ErrorCount;Hostname;"totalRows"
1471603013666;709;01_Login;200;OK;Search 3-1;text;true;14632;1;4;;651;1;0;vm-jmter.net;null`

Comment: @veera Is this the only content? Are you seeing any error when you try to open jtl? can you check jmeter.log file? or enable logs on JMeter UI? Did you use -l option to save the jtl file?

Comment: These are the first 2 lines in the jtl file.  I have a hug file and when I tried to load the partial file, it was displaying values correctly.  Looks like jmeter did not capture values for some period of time due to disk space issue.  I have understood that that this might be the reason for zero ART value.  Thanks for your willingness to help me.

Comment: if the problem is resolved accept the answer so that can close this thread.